# How to filter array (x,y,z) with (0,0)<=(x,y)<=(x1,y1) in numpy or python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np.array like blow, the form is (x,y,z).

```
[[  -1,100,1],
 [   2,2,3],
 [   4,1,1],
 [   100,100,1],
 ]
```

I want to filter it with (0,0)<(x,y)<(4,4),get a new array.

```
[[   2,2,3],
 [   4,1,1],
 ]
```

I had filtered a array which the form is (x,y).

```
aa = np.array([[  -1,100],
 [   2,2],
 [   4,1],
 [   100,100],
 ]   )
ll = np.array([0, 0]) 
ur = np.array([4, 4])

bb = np.all(np.logical_and(ll <= aa, aa <= ur), axis=1)
aa[bb]


array([[2, 2],
       [4, 1]])
```

But How to do when (x,y,z)?
Thanks!

Comment: Just do the comparison for those specific indices (columns). `bb = np.all(np.logical_and(ll <= aa[:,:-1], aa[:,:-1] <= ur), axis=1)`

Comment: @Kasrâmvd this is the answer to the question, you should post it as is. This will help others find it more easily and give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Kasrâmvd.
Use the code .

```
bb = np.all(np.logical_and(ll <= aa[:,:-1], aa[:,:-1] <= ur), axis=1)

array([[2, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 1]])
```